# firebase network-request-failed error in ec2 instance

Tags: firebase, amazon-ec2

I used firebase to implement the login feature. It works without any problems in local. However, when I deployed it to an ec2 instance and ran it, I got a Firebase: Error (auth/network-request-failed) error. Does anyone know how to fix it?

anyone, please help me...

Comment: Are you running a client app on your EC2 instance?  Are you using the Client SDK or the Admin SDK? Can your EC2 instance access services on the internet?  Are you able to `ping identitytoolkit.googleapis.com` from the EC2 instance?